# decode response of get request for persian websites

Tags: python, gzip, decoding, transfer-encoding

I'm writing function for send request and get response of websites and parse of content of it...
but when i send request to persian sites it cant decode content of it

```python
def gather_links(page_url):
    html_string = ''
    try:
        response = urlopen(page_url)
        if 'text/html' in response.getheader('Content-Type'):
            html_bytes = response.read()
            html_string = html_bytes.decode("utf-8")    
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
```

show this ERROR for example https://www.entekhab.ir/ :

> 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in position 1: invalid start byte

how can i change the code for decode this kind of sites too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/master/) instead of urllib.

```
import requests

response = requests.get('https://www.entekhab.ir/')
print(response.text)
```

Comment: ye its work better and correctly work...request lib have any difference  urllib.request packages?

Comment: `requests` is better and everybody uses it.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that the url's content is compressed with gzip, which urlopen does not seem to handle by default:

```
>>> r = request.urlopen('https://www.entekhab.ir/')
>>> print(r.info())
Server: sepehr-proxy-1.2-rc3
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Connection: close
Content-Length: 81269
Date: Sat, 28 Sep 2019 14:41:49 GMT
Content-Encoding: gzip
```

Therefore, you need to decompress the response before decoding:

```
>>> import gzip
>>> bs = gzip.decompress(r.read())
>>> bs.decode('utf-8')[:113]
'<!-- 2019/09/28 18:16:08 --><!DOCTYPE html> <html lang="fa-IR" dir="rtl"> <head>           <meta charset="utf-8">'
```

As user askaroni's answer points out, the `requests` package handles this case automatically, and even the Python urllib docs recommend using it.  Nevertheless, it's useful to understand *why* the response could not be decoded immediately.

Comment: Thanks a lot ... Ye your answer so professionally and you Solve the problem from the base